# Digital signing algorithms with two keys

Tags: encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I have been researching digital signing a bit, and have read about private and public keys. Here is how I got it:

1. Someone has message `M` and generates signature `S = SomeAlgorithm1(PrivateKey, M)`
2. Receiving side gets message `M` and signature `S`
3. Receiving side does decoding of signature like `result = SomeAlgorithm2(PublicKey, S)` and checks if `result == M`.
4. If it is everything is fine.

But ff someone else knows the public key, and generates random signature `S` and does `M = SomeAlgorithm2(PublicKey, S)` and sends `M` and `S` to receiving side.
And receiving side does the thing from step 3 above, and says it is fine, althoguh it is not... They would probably get some message which doesnt have much sense.

My question is, is that message with no sense the only thing that makes this hacking impossible? In theory if that message is sensible message the hack would succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually signing involves a hash of the message ...

so the (simplified) procedure is

take your Message M and calculate H1 = hash(M)

Take your Private Key Kpriv and calculate S = sign(H1,KPriv)

Attach S to M and transfer to recipient

the recipient calculates H2 = hash(M)

and then takes your Public Key KPub and calculates verify(S,KPub,H2) = true / false

(since you mention in step 3 something like 'decoding' of a signature...) you may be familiar with the fact that in the RSA case the operations behind sign() and verify() are indeed encrypt() and decrypt(), but please be aware that this does not hold for every signature algorithm, and is indeed a special case with RSA

so maybe things will become clearer if we take a look at an example:

in the RSA case the verify(S,KPub,H2) from above is: H2 == decrypt(S,KPub)

this works for RSA since from the mathematical point of view, the public and private exponent are interchangable and the mathematical operation behind encrypt and decrypt is very much the same ... so that the above becomes H2 == POW(POW(H1,d),e) mod N ... N is the Modulus, d is the private exponent, e is the public exponent ... since e and d are choosen (at keypair creation) so that e*d mod phi(N) = 1 ... with phi() being eulers phi function ... the calculation becomes H2==POW(H1,1) mod N ... (fermat's little theorem) ... which boils down to H2 == H1 ...

H1 was calculated by the signer ... H2 was calculated by the recipient ... if those two match each other there is a certain likelyhood that the message is authentic ... of course if an attacker can choose M and M' with hash(M)==hash(M'), in other words if someone can find a hash collision for 2 messages, the signature becomes useless... you will have verify(S,KPub,hash(M'))== true even though the signer has never seen M'

so with having said all of this ... back to your initial question ...

what happens if an attacker exercises his knowledge of what is calculated in verify() or in your example SomeAlgorithm2() ...?

lets strip the hash from all of this ... and instead of handling hashes we directly operate on the message M ...

YES indeed, in the RSA example, the attacker can recover M from S in this case (assuming M is small enough to not be truncated by mod N)

but the attacker will get the original message ... M ... which he already knows ... so yes... he can send that to someone else ... together with S ... which he also already knows ...

he does not win anything because he can not alter M without breaking the signature ...

as already said... RSA is a special case because encryption, decryption signing and verify ... all boils down to the same mathematical operation ...

as soon as you include hashing all you can recover is the hash ... but still the very same hash that was signed

with other algorithms, you sometimes don't have anything else that true/false in the end ...

but all of this is not the point ... that information you are talking about is not secret ... it is indeed the very same information that was signed ...

the attacker needs not only to get that information from the verify process... he needs to be able to actually change something in M and calculate the resulting change to S ...

if he can do that he has broken the signature algorithm

as an alternative he can try and break the hash function as described above ... in that case he didn't really break the signature because it's still the same value ... but he was able to break the system that had the goal to prove the authenticity of M ... it's like a chain of trust ... it's as strong as the weakest link

the whole topic is a lot more complex than this, but i think this is ok as a simplified rundown for beginners...there are attack vectors that can expose the private key if an RSA signature system is implemented in this simplified way without further precautions ... so ... DON'T!

this is only meant to show what's actually going on with signing and verifying in this case ... for a real world implementation you will need to include padding and further message structures and identifiers ... way to complex for a simple SO answer ...

Comment: Thanks very much, nice explanation.